# Weird program behavior when streaming data to files before using seekg and tellg

Tags: c++, fstream

I'll try to be as clear as I can: Whenever I try to stream data to my file before my 'do' loop and my pointers reading and writing, my program goes nuts! It appears to be running an infinite loop.

```
fstream fileHandler; //Can also be done via constructor fstream fileHanlder("myData.txt", ios::out);
//fileHandler.open("myData.txt", ios::out);//Default is in AND out

fileHandler.open("test.txt", ios::in | ios::binary | ios::out);

if (fileHandler.is_open()) {

    //fileHandler << "anything" <---HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    cout << "The file has been opened and edited properly.";

    fileHandler.seekg(0, ios::end);
    streampos sizeOfFile = fileHandler.tellg();//tellg returns type streampos
    fileHandler.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    do{
        string buffer;
        fileHandler >> buffer;
        cout << buffer << endl;

    }while(!fileHandler.eof());

    if ((fileHandler.rdstate()^ifstream::eofbit) == 0) {
        fileHandler.clear();
        cout << fileHandler.tellg() << endl;
    }


    fileHandler.close();

} else cout << "There was a problem opening the file!";
```

My file has nothing but a simple phrase.

EDIT: fixed the title according to new information
Thanks for any attention!

Comment: By the time your program is running the compiler is completely out of the picture. Since you're not checking if your input succeeded it's not surprising you're stuck. `eof` is almost never the right condition in a loop. If your file is binary, why are you reading it into a string? What is the contents of the file?

Comment: I tried setting the binary flag as a debug attempt. It happens the same thing without it. My .txt file has only a simple phrase

Comment: How about that you have created the fstream as read only (ios::in), but are trying to write to it?  I would also get rid of the ios::binary so that you will read "text" from the stream.

Comment: Yeah...so strange. With 'out' it had no effect. But with 'out' and without binary, it stopped. Thank you very much though. If you want to reply, I'll give you the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the binary flag fixed it for some reason.